Firestore Vector and findNearest in Flutter
Lately, Firestore added Vector search as showed here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/vector-search
The code example to add a FieldValue.vector([...]) are in python and Node.js
Does Dart library cloud_firestore have the FieldValue.Vector to save a document?
What about the method collection.find_nearest to query?

firebaser here
tl;dr: The ability to read, write and search on vector data in Firestore is currently only available in the (server-side) Node.js and Python SDKs. It is not yet available in any of the client-side SDKs. It will be added to the client-side SDKs at some point, including the one for Flutter, but there is no public timeline for this.
If you want to use vectors data and vector searches today, here are some workarounds that can already work.
Accessing vector data from the Flutter app
If you access a document with vector data from your Flutter code, be careful that you don't wipe out that vector data when writing back to the database. So only use update calls or set-with-merge to prevent accidentally deleting any existing vector data.
Performing a query with vector search from the Flutter app
As said above, the ability to query on vector fields is also only available in the server-side SDKs for Node and Python. It is not yet available in any of the client-side SDKs, including the one for Flutter.
A workaround is to implement search functionality is to implement it in Cloud Functions that trigger on data writes to Firestore, and then access those Firestore documents in your Flutter application. Step-wise:

Write your search vector (and any other data needed) from the Flutter app to Firestore.
Have a Cloud Function (in Node or Python) trigger on this write.
Have the Cloud Function call the vector search API, and write the results back to the document.
Have you Flutter app listen to updates to the document, and get the search results from there.


That is easier said than done. The linked Google documentation is quite incomplete and debugging cloud functions is very slow. Isn't there somewhere a working example?
Can't I upload the vector directly as an Array of Numbers?

If you are new to JavaScript, programming Cloud Functions for Firebase is indeed not the easiest to get started with. You might want to start with a local Node script to get the interaction with the database working, so you can debug it with a local debugger. After that you'll be much better equipped to port that code to Cloud Functions, and debugging those in the local emulator suite will give you a faster roundtrip - all before doing the slower roundtrip of deploying to Google.

If you're having a hard time making this work, post a new question with a minimal repro of where you got stuck - so we can have a look.
